# MacOS c++でopenCVが実行できない

Tags: c++, macos, opencv

以下のtest.cppファイルを

```cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
int main(){
    cv::Mat a = cv::imread("test.jpg", 1); 
    cv::imshow("hello", a); 
    cv::waitKey();
}
```

次のように実行したところ、
`c++ -std=c++14 test.cpp -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.0.1/include/opencv4`
次のようなエラーが出て実行できませんでした。

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::Mat::deallocate()", referenced from:
      cv::Mat::release() in test-4fd227.o
  "cv::imread(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in test-4fd227.o
  "cv::imshow(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
      _main in test-4fd227.o
  "cv::waitKey(int)", referenced from:
      _main in test-4fd227.o
  "cv::fastFree(void*)", referenced from:
      cv::Mat::~Mat() in test-4fd227.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

`/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.0.1/include/opencv4`にはopencv2フォルダがあり、中にはopencv.hppを含んだ大量のhppファイルがあるので、おそらくopenCVの本体だと思っています。

どうすれば動くようになりますか？

### 環境

macOS Mojave 10.14.2
通常のc++コードはコンパイル＆実行できる。
brew経由でインストール

### 2019 3/29 0:20追記

- `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.0.1/lib`にはlibade.aとかlibopencv_aruco.4.0.1.dylibといった名前のファイルがありますが、この場所がライブラリパスでしょうか？
- `c++ -std=c++14 test.cpp -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.0.1/include/opencv4 -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.0.1/include/opencv4/opencv2 -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.0.1/lib`を実行しても同じエラーが出てしまいます…

### 2019 4/4 14:33追記

- `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.0.1/lib/pkgconfig`というフォルダがあり、中に`opencv4.pc`だけ入っている。

### 2019 4/6 20:42追記

- 以下の手順で解決に至った。
- 環境変数`PKG_CONFIG_PATH`が作られてなかったので、`~/.bash_profile`に`exportPKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/"`を追加。

Comment: コンパイラフラグに`-I`でインクルード指定しかしておらず、`-L`でライブラリーをリンク指定しなければいけないのではないでしょうか

Comment: OpenCVをどうやってインストールしましたか? brew? port? pkgconfigのファイルがインストールされていませんか?

Comment: @int32_t brewでインストールしました。`/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.0.1/lib/pkgconfig`というフォルダを見つけました。中には`opencv4.pc`のみが入ってました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ヘッダファイルの場所を指定すために `-I`、
ライブラリの場所を指定するために `-L`、
リンクするライブラリを指定するために `-l` (小文字エル) が必要です。

```
c++ -std=c++14 test.cpp -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.0.1/include/opencv4 \
    -L/usr/loal/Cellar/opencv/4.0.1/lib \
    -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_core
```

こんなフラグをいちいち指定していては面倒すぎるので、`pkg-config` という便利な仕組みがあります。

```
brew install pkg_config
```

とすると、`/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/` に `opencv4.pc` が作成されているはずです。

```
pkg-config --cflags opencv4
```

を実行するとOpenCVを利用したビルドに必要な`-I`フラグを表示します。

```
pkg-config --libs opencv4
```

を実行するとOpenCVを利用したビルドに必要な`-L`と`-l`を表示します。
これらを利用して、

```
c++ -std=c++14 test.cpp `pkg-config --cflags opencv4` `pkg-config --libs opencv4`
```

と書けば長いパスをいちいち書かず、ライブラリ名を気にせずにビルドすることができます。

Answer (score 0):

"/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.0.1/include/opencv4にはopencv2フォルダがあり、中にはopencv.hppを含んだ大量のhppファイルがある"

・".hpp"というファイル拡張子はC++のヘッダーファイルですので、それが大量にあるフォルダーはヘッダファイルへのパスであるインクルードパスに含めるべきものと思われます。

・ヘッダファイルはC++のプログラムの本体ではありませんから、「おそらくopenCVの本体だと」というのは正しくない可能性が高いと思います。

・”Undefined symbols ”のエラーが起きるのは、個々のC++プログラムをコンパイルした後に、コンパイルされたコードやライブラリを統合（リンク）して実行プログラムを生成する段階ですから、問題は必要なライブラリが無い、もしくはライブラリのパスに問題があるのだと思われます。

＝＝
以上の観測から、
１）C++のオプションにライブラリパスを追加する　(-Lオプション）
２）念のためインクルードパスにopencvフォルダーも含める　
"-I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.0.1/include/opencv4/opencv2"　も指定する。

を試してみては如何でしょう

Comment: -Lを付けても同じエラーが出ました（コマンドの内容は追記に書きました）。`c++ ライブラリパス 確認方法`のように検索しても分からなかったのですが、openCVの正しいライブラリパスを確認するにはどうすればいいですか？

Comment: `-L`オプションは`-I`オプションがディレクトリーを指定するのとは異なり、リンクするライブラリーファイルを個別に指定する必要があります。